# Is there a mistake in this linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

It seems to me that the $x_i$ and the $\overline{x}$ switch places and when the chain rule is applied there is also a $-2$ that I cannot justify as to why it is negative.

When I try to derive this myself I get a similarly structured solution, but with different signs because I don't see how this is correct.

Comment: derivative of $-\theta_1(x_i-\bar x)$ is $-(x_i-\bar x)$, there is a minus. Why don't you ask why the $(x_i-\bar x)$ at the end goes with no minus, and what happened with its minus? The minus was written in front of the $2$.

Comment: No mistake.....

Comment: @Mirko my confusion happens before what you said... my confusion is coming from the far RHS of the equation at the top. How do we get from there to the equation just below the line, and why is the 2 negative?

Comment: simple arithmetic that you should be able to immediately verify. Distribute the minus in the middle pair of parentheses. Group that $\theta_1$ with the last $\theta_1$ (the right pair of parentheses). Use paper and pencil, if necessary.

Comment: yes I see that now, but I still don't see why the 2 should be negative

Comment: because read my first comment, derivative of $-\theta_1$ is $-1$. The two is positive, it was just multiplied by $-1$ that came from $-\theta_1$, if this point of view is of any help. When you try to derive you do not have to "see why this is correct", you should not look at all at this, when you derive on your own. You should be able to derive the correct answer without looking at this. If you are looking at this, then you are not doing it on your own, and then you would not get it.